# Print Elements of ArrayList in order of input string

Tags: java, arraylist

What I am trying to do is, get input string from user. Add it into arraylist since i have to play with characters later. But first i want to print contents of ArrayList in order to check what is exactly in their. Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List <String> Vowels = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("What is your string? ");
    String abc = sc.nextLine();
    int n = abc.length();
    for(int i=0; i <= n-1 ; i++)
    {
        Vowels.add(sc.nextLine());
    }

    for(int j=0; j< Vowels.size();j++)
        System.out.println(Vowels.get(j));

}
```

It is not printing anything or not showing up any error. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The `sc.nextLine()` in your for loop is going to block waiting for user input.  Your logic is strange as well I think.  If you enter the word "wally" then the for loop is going to require you to enter 5 more lines.  Is this right?

Comment: Yes yes.. that is exactly what is happening! 5 more lines! How can I resolve that?

Comment: try writing proper code.  The java program is doing exactly what you are asking it to.  It is 100% correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is your problem:

```
for(int i=0; i <= n-1 ; i++)
{
    Vowels.add(sc.nextLine());
               ^
}
```

*"It is not printing anything"* because it waiting for your input

What you need is:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List <String> Vowels = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("What is your string? ");
    String abc = sc.nextLine();
    int n = abc.length();
    for(int i=0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        Vowels.add(new StringBuilder().append("").append(abc.charAt(i)).toString());
    }

    for(int j=0; j< Vowels.size();j++)
        System.out.print(Vowels.get(j));
}
```

**Input :** `Burger`

**Output:** `Burger`

If you want your output as `[B, u, r, g, e, r]`, then just do:

```
System.out.println(Vowels); //without for loop
```

Comment: I gave input like "Burger". Its not printing after that. I want it to print [B,U,R,G,E,R] or better "Burger" as it is as input.

Comment: @RafaEl It is working now but it is printing as one character per line.. I want to print it as a string. How that can be done?

Comment: @GauravK. you want to print it in one line? then just use `System.out.print(Vowels.get(j));`

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your new requirements as in Rafa El's comments, try

```
abc = "Burger";          // use abc = sc.nextLine();
int n = abc.length();
for(int i=0; i < n ; i++)
{
    Vowels.add("" + abc.charAt(i));
}
```